# Tab layout swipe direction

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Can I change the swipe direction of Tabs in TabLayout by code?

It works fine when my device's language is English, But when I change it to Arabic, A lot of tabs disappear and the swipe's direction still the same (to The Right ).
Note: In Manifest file support RTL option is "true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem you facing is the fact, that `ViewPager` still does not support RTL.

It's well-known and very old issue - you can find it in Google's issue tracker:
[ViewPager RTL swipe direction](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56831)

So far, I haven't seen any successful examples of RLT's implementation. For, example, there's one from [Booking.com](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager), but it [doesn't work with TabLayout](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager/issues/1) yet. I'd suggest to dig into it and try to fix the issue there, than start writing it from scratch.

**UPD:** I forked Booking's RtlViewPager and fix it for TabLayout's. [Feel free to try it](https://github.com/ksloginov/RtlViewPager)!

[image]

Comment: @Maysara I believe, I fixed Booking's ViewPager. Check it in my github - https://github.com/ksloginov/RtlViewPager :-)

Comment: Really
 <<< u r amazing !
Thank u very much 
: )

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov I think your fix is only working when the tablayout has no scroll in it, I mean when all tabs are displayed. I tried with a scrolled TabLayout so tab titles are not split like in your example image, but it is doing weird movements :(

Comment: @Shyri oh, that's an interesting feedback. I'll check it our over the weekend if it's fixable. Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov I found a way to override this behaviour and make it work together with tour fork of RTLViewPager. Basically TabLayout is performing some operations to the x coordinate before performing scrollTo() method. I've overwritten them to undo this changes and perform same modification but for the opposite direction. I've uploaded a Gist for it, check it out here let me know what you think: 
https://gist.github.com/Shyri/be70ceb101c98b3d457f7ff43b7f1c40 
Thanks you!

Answer (score 6):

You can easily change `layoutDirection`. i had this problem too and fix by :

```
tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

Just try it!

Answer (score 3):

There are two simple steps you need to follow:

1. Change the rotation of the View pager,

   ```
   viewpager.setRotationY(180);
   ```
2. Then again change the direction of the fragment container which is the child of viewpager,

   ```
   recyclerView.setRotationY(180);
   ```

---

[image]

Comment: changing rotation is not a good idea. I know it's working but I have seen on some of devices that changing rotation will affect on views in fragment to be invisible (views are in the fragment but you can't see them). I have seen this in some of huawei devices.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue is well known](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56831) and there is no ETA for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code `tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);`